# Excel: Matching names based on a matrix of options (Employees provide a list of people they want to meet with)

Tags: excel

I have a list of 140 people, and each person is giving me 8 names of employees they would like to meet with.

Given time constraints, we'll try to match them with 5 people to meet or so, with the understanding that they might not get all of their choices, but we want to maximize their choices.

As such, I've currently laid out the data as follows:

**Column A**: The 140 employees (so 140 rows)
**Column B**: Each employee's option 1 (first name they listed of person they want to meet)
**Column C**: Option 2...etc. 
...
**Column I**: Option 8

I'm not sure what is the best way to generate matches as we're trying to maximize based on their list.

My initial gut reaction is to do something like --> Look at columns B through I and see if any of those employees have also said they want to meet with the submitting employee (Column A). As such, we can begin filling like that first.

However, I'm having trouble finding an elegant solution to do this?

Anyone have any suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: I would probably attack this as a more formal optimization problem. Excel has a built-in optimizer (Solver) but that is for small problems only. You are suggesting some kind of heuristic. These are typically sub-optimal. By how much is difficult to say without a real optimization model.

Comment: Thanks, how should I best go about solving this from an optimization standpoint? or do you have any suggestions on where I can look to read up on this?

Comment: Well, **Integer Programming** comes to mind. Google will find you an almost infinite number of hits.

Comment: If it's helpful for anyone, my temporary solution (before reading into integer programming) is to basically use a combination of OR, Concatenate, Indirect and Vlookups to basically check if any submitting employee has a match with any of the guys on his list who have mentioned the submitting employee as someone they also want to meet.

Answer (score 0):

This can be modeled as an integer programming optimization problem. I assume here `employee` and `person` is the same. I.e. person `a` has a wish list as well as person `b`. If `b` is on `a`'s list and `a` on `b`'s list then you get 2 points if matching `a` with `b`.

My attempt: use

```
x(i,j,t) = 1 if person i meets person j in round t
           0 otherwise
```

The constraints are:

- In each round meet exactly one person
- Persons a and b can meet at most one time

The preferences can be modeled as a score `prefs(i,j)`. Where `prefs(i,j)=1` if preferred. We can generalize this to any number: larger numbers means more preference (and a negative number means: I don't want to meet this person).

This leads to a very large, but easy MIP model. We can exploit symmetry to reduce the size of the problem by half. I.e. we always have

```
 x(a,b,t) = x(b,a,t)  for persons a and b
```

So we would like to use binary decision variables  `x(i,j,t)` only where `j < i`. This makes the otherwise simple model slightly more complicated:

[image]

For 140 persons and 5 rounds we get about 48k variables! This looks daunting but the model solves easily. A minute or so.